# How can I prevent quick suggestions in VS Code when prepending to a word?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I want to prevent VS Code from prompting suggestion if cursor not at then end of word.

for example, I have several variable with first character in uppercase and I want to modify to lowercase.

```
// modify first character to lowercase

uint32_t Count;
         ↑
        cursor
=>
uint32_t count;
```

When I modify "C" to "c", the cursor is not at then end of the word, but the suggestion window still prompt, and it is very annoying, I have to press ESC to close it.

So how to prevent suggestion if the cursor is not at then end of the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported right now(?). The [info that I can find](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30811#issuecomment-315688097) (from 2017, so could very well be outdated) says quick suggestions are not supposed to trigger in the middle of words. That largely seems to be accurate. I guess your specific case (assuming you are typing at the beginning of the word) doesn't count as being "in the middle of a word".

I don't know exactly what relation this has to the `editor.wordSeparators` setting. I tried to set the word separator set to empty (which includes excluding `.`), but that didn't seem to help. I suppose you could disable quick suggestions entirely, but you might not want to do that.